# How to create an SSRS layout report dynamically

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I want to create an SSRS report that displays tables dynamically.

The report can display one table or multiples tables horizontally as the following two samples . [Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl189.png) [Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLYrK.png)

What is the best approach of solving the above report. I need the solution to be from Report Builder tool and explain in details how to create it using which data regions.

Thank you in advance.

B.Regards,

ITB Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you could build this out using a [multi-column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159107.aspx) report.